# How to count total number of rows of an access database table?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

```
string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\Users\yogi\Documents\mydb.mdb";
string cmdstr = "select * from quant_level1";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
con.Open();
OleDbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
DataSet data = new DataSet();
int i = data.Tables["quant_level1"].Rows.Count;
Label2.Text = i.ToString();
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

use

```
string cmdstr = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quant_level1";
```

With `com.ExecuteScalar()`

```
using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(constr))
using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, conn)) 
{
    conn.Open();
    int count = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

`ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query, here it give you row count.

you can use `OleDbDataReader` as you try in your code sample. but need to change the logic bit.

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
using (OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("select * from quant_level1", con))
{
    con.Open();
    using (OleDbDataReader myReader = com.ExecuteReader())
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(myReader);
        int count = dt.Rows.Count;
    }
}
```

**Why you fail!**

You have created data set but you haven't load data to dataset using your DataReader. So you will get zero row count at the end.

Comment: Typo in `Cout` (=> `Count`). Also don't forget to indicate to beginners that all class that implements IDisposable (like `OleDbCommand`, `OleDbConnection`, ...) **MUST** be disposed. ;-)

Comment: *MUST* is very strong, it is however *highly recommended* as it will clean up resources early i.e. when no longer needed rather than wait for garbage collection; when the finalizer gets a chance to clean up if not already disposed.

Comment: @ShaunWilde You are right, I probably didn't use the good word :) What I would like to say, is like it's good to indicate to beginners that it's recommended to use Parameterized statements instead of building string query to prevent SQL injection, it's maybe good to put some words about this...

Comment: @Chris - I agree there are best practices we must try to adhere to but we should know why they are there rather than following rules absolutely. I have seen some awfully slow code because of `using` statements where they would have been better holding on to it and perhaps wrapping it in their own IDisposable.

Comment: @ShaunWilde Again, you are probably right. I have not used the good word (must).  And we don't have enough  information to tell what should be do here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that you want to fill your `DataSet` and count the rows later:

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(com);  
da.Fill(data);
int i = data.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
Label2.Text = i.ToString();
```

If you just want to count the rows, you can change the query to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quant_level1` and get the return value like this:

```
int i = (int) com.ExecuteScalar();
Label2.Text = i.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
   Select count(*) from  quant_level1
```

Change the command syntax  executescalar to retrieve a single value

```
CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM region";   
Int32 count = (int32) ExecuteScalar();
```

Hope this can enlighten you a bit